# Writing a console-based C++ IRC-client

Tags: c++, sockets, ncurses, event-driven

I'm learning C++ and so I've decided to begin coding a IRC-Client.

I basically want it to be consolebased, and I've looked in to libraries such as ncurses, but I don't really know whether or not this would be the best approach.

I imagine the UI being divided into one part where whatever messages are written appear, and one part where the users input goes. Ncurses seemed to be able to do this, but now I've discovered another issue.

Because I want the message-part to be event driven (whenever somebody sends a message, this should appear in the message-part) the message-part of the UI should run independently from the input-part. Also, sockets would have to be non-blocking as well.

I've looked around on the internet and haven't found any good tutorials on this, as most are either really, really old, poorly written or simply just to long.

Anyways, my questions are, how would this be done using the ncurses and socket libraries? Are their any good C++ wrappers (one thing I've learned from reading ncurses tutorials is that OOP is really wonderful...)?

Comment: Also, don't forget - C++ is not just an Object Oriented language. It's a multi-paradigm language.  C Api's are a perfectly fine set of libraries to use with C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ncurses for the interface sounds like a good idea. You can do a single-threaded select-based network and terminal client -- check out [Beej's guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). Alternatively, Boost.asio, single-or-multithreaded, should be a solid choice, too.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need to use a few threads to do that, so I'd take a look at [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).
However, you shouldn't be afraid of long tutorials, because what you're trying to achieve is not so simple, specially if C++ is the first computer language you learn.

Comment: I'd suggest `boost::thread` or C++0x `std::thread` to a beginner. It's got a friendlier interface, and has the advantage of being cross-platform.

Comment: Threads are harder than most people think, though.  I believe Touzen is right in attempting to use a non-blocking approach, although that isn't easy, either.